# how do i program a web view to play a stream and still access other functions of my iPhone app Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, webview, streaming, xcode5

I am using a single page app in Xcode 5, one WebView. i want to have access to other functions of my app while the stream is playing. only options in web view are the done button which stops the stream, is there a way to disable the done/stop function and write a new manual stop so that i can have users enjoy multiple functions of the app?